# Удаление элементов из списка по из содержанию

Tags: python, list

На вход подается произвольный список со значениями
['abc', 'cba', 'acb', 'bca']. При этом, я не знаю, под каким индексом идет определенный элемент. Нужно определить его содержание (у меня есть догадка про for) и удалить 'acb'

Comment: Как ни странно, индекс можно найти с помощью index()

Comment: Можно так же использовать функцию filter()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = ['abc', 'cba', 'acb', 'bca']

for i in a: # это цикл i который проходится по списку a
    if i == 'acb': # если какая-то из итераций цикла for равна 'acb'
        a.remove('acb') # удаляем элемент по его имени
        
print(a) # выводим результат
```

Решение верно если правильно понял вопрос.

Comment: А на кой искать, если remove само это делает?

Comment: Потому что KirNsk написал что нужно определить содержание списка.

Comment: Метод remove ведь удалит, в случае если только найдёт.

Comment: Думаю у KirNsk не возникнет сложностей в написании блока else :)